# Linear Algebra: Prove intersection of two planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, plane-geometry, intersection-theory

I have this Algebra question:

Prove that the equation for the intersecting line between the planes $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n_1}=0$ and $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n_2}=0$
is given by $\vec{r}=t(\vec{n_1}\times\vec{n_2})$.

I can see from the equations that both planes go through origin and that a cross product vector of the normals will give the line vector through the origin, which is what the question is about. The problem is how to prove this in a correct way.

Is it enough to replace $\vec{r}$ in the first two equations which are still true:
$$t(\vec{n_1}\times\vec{n_2})\cdot\vec{n_1}=0$$$$t(\vec{n_1}\times\vec{n_2})\cdot\vec{n_1}=0$$

The line vector lies in both planes and since both planes go through origin the intersecting line will as well.

How do I do this with some beautiful math jargon that will satisfy the grumpiest of math professors?

Than you.

Comment: As you've explained, the given line clearly is common to both planes; furthermore, since two planes have at most one intersection line, therefore *the* required intersection line must be the given one.